# Equal width of floating columns

Tags: html, css

I have problem with setting equal width of four floating divs.
First and last div, must be at container sides, gap between each div (and div width) must be the same.

Like this: |[] [] [] []|
(where | = container side, [] = div).

I make another divs to control margins, but it didnt work.

HTML & SCSS:

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 50px 0px;
}
.wrapper .services-box {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0 20px 20px 0;
}
.wrapper .services-box:nth-of-type(4n+4) {
  padding: 0 0 20px 0;
}
.wrapper .services-box .service {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="services-box">
    <div class="service">
      <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </p>
          <a href="#">More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="services-box">
    <div class="service">
      <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </p>
          <a href="#">More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="services-box">
    <div class="service">
      <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </p>
          <a href="#">More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="services-box">
    <div class="service">
      <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </p>
          <a href="#">More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there chance to slove this without using js/calc/flexbox?

[IMAGE OF ISSUE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVpR5.png)

Comment: Why don't you want to use flexbox, which could do this in its sleep?

Comment: Add `* { box-sizing: border-box; }`.

Comment: There is border-box for whole page, just didnt add it to this code.

Need ie9 support, thats why no flexbox

Comment: I only added it and it works. Check the snippet in my answer.

Comment: @connexo it's not. Last col is bigger - run debugger and you will see that :/ Thats mine problem.

Comment: Uhm.
.services-box 0 20px 20px 0;

4th div : 0 0 20px 0; (bottom 20px)

Comment: If you have to avoid `calc` as well your only remaining option is to apply %-margins to the first (or last) three containers.

Comment: I hope there is a cheat for this, for example with negative margins or sth like that.

Comment: I adjusted my answer to solve the problem based on % margins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `padding` you set on the boxes, by default, increases the elements width causing them to wrap on new lines when the available space is not enough.

To fix it you can add this to your CSS, which makes for a more predictable behaviour:

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

This is the complete working demo:

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.wrapper {
  margin-left: -20px; /* Absorb the gutters */
  padding: 50px 0px;
}
.wrapper .services-box {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0 0 20px 20px;
}
/*.wrapper .services-box:nth-of-type(4n+4) {
  padding: 0 0 20px 0;
}*/
.wrapper .services-box .service {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="services-box">
    <div class="service">
      <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        <p>
          <a href="#">More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="services-box">
    <div class="service">
      <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        <p>
          <a href="#">More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="services-box">
    <div class="service">
      <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        <p>
          <a href="#">More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="services-box">
    <div class="service">
      <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        <p>
          <a href="#">More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Still not. 4th interior div (151px) 1-3 div (131px)

Comment: @Krece right, by removing the padding on the last element it actually increases its content width. I modified the answer so that the spacing is always applied on the left and the wrapper has a negative margin-left to compensate it.

Comment: Thats what I will do. Now I see the problem in my code (with full site). Just need to add another container and your idea should work :) Will test it.

Comment: Check it. It makes all divs to move left by 20px (last too). So last is not at end of container.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the padding from the `.services-box`:

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 50px 0px;
}
.wrapper .services-box {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}
.wrapper .services-box .service {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.wrapper .services-box:first-child .service {
  padding-left: 0;
}
.wrapper .services-box:last-child .service {
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="services-box">
    <div class="service">
      <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<p>
      <a href="#">More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="services-box">
    <div class="service">
      <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<p>
      <a href="#">More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="services-box">
    <div class="service">
      <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<p>
      <a href="#">More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="services-box">
    <div class="service">
      <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<p>
      <a href="#">More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another option is to set the width of each container to 20% and calculate the rest ((100-80)/3) == 6.66%) for the margin-right of each container (without the last one).

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 50px 0px;
}
.wrapper .services-box {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  margin-right: 6.6%;
}
.wrapper .services-box .service {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.wrapper .services-box:first-child .service {
  padding-left: 0;
}
.wrapper .services-box:last-child .service {
  padding-right: 0;
}
.wrapper .services-box:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="services-box">
    <div class="service">
      <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<p>
      <a href="#">More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="services-box">
    <div class="service">
      <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<p>
      <a href="#">More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="services-box">
    <div class="service">
      <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<p>
      <a href="#">More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="services-box">
    <div class="service">
      <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<p>
      <a href="#">More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can use 20(*4)+6.66(*3) or 22(*4)+4(*3) or any other combination that suits you.

Comment: then I will have 4 equal divs without any gap between.
And 20px at .service is interior padding of content div. Need to operate on .services-box padding/margin

Comment: You do have gap between them because you have the `.service` class with padding.

Comment: And I have 20px gap from the main container .wrapper, there must be no gap.

Comment: Removed this gap using `:first-child` and `:last-child`. Check the update.

Comment: Then first and last child is bigger than 2nd and 3rd.

Comment: Each `.services-box` is 151.68px, are you sure?

Comment: Each of .services-box is, but interior .service is not (4th is 151, others are 131).

Comment: Padding is part of the width. If you want you can switch to `margin-right` (instead of the padding), note that this way your right-most box will also have padding (which I'm not sure you want).

Comment: @Krece, check the second part of my answer (the second snippet with the percentages).

Comment: Its not making last div to be at container box

Comment: what? I don't understand your comment

Comment: I didnt understand you before - your idea working fine. But... its not pixel perfect :|

Comment: well.. a vote on the answer will be nice :) regarding the "pixel-perfect" - when you use percentages it's a bit hard to also have the solution works 100% for pixels. You can try use the `calc` function (css, not js). `width: calc(25%-50px)`. It might give you the solution you are looking for.

Comment: Just found ultimate simply pixel perfect way.
`&:nth-of-type(1) {
                padding: 0 30px 0 0;
            }
            &:nth-of-type(2) {
                padding: 0 20px 0 10px;
            }
            &:nth-of-type(3) {
                padding: 0 10px 0 20px;
            }
            &:nth-of-type(4) {
                padding: 0 0 0 30px;
            }`

In total - 4 columns, with 25%, with pixel perfect gap between.

Comment: Not sure I understand, can you provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

Just add `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` and it works as you expected. If you go with standard `box-sizing: content-box;` paddings are *added* to container widths.

```css
html,
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
}
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: grey;
}
.services-box {
  background-color: orange;
  float: left;
  width: 24.25%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.services-box:nth-of-type(4n+4) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.service {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="services-box">
    <div class="service">
      <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        <p>
          <a href="#">More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="services-box">
    <div class="service">
      <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        <p>
          <a href="#">More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="services-box">
    <div class="service">
      <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        <p>
          <a href="#">More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="services-box">
    <div class="service">
      <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        <p>
          <a href="#">More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 4th div is bigger in this case.

Comment: Instead of `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` I'd prefer `html, body { box-sizing: border-box; }` combined with `* { box-sizing: inherit; }`. This way if you need to change box sizing on parts of your page you only need to change it for the top node.

Comment: Agreed. Was just aiming for a quickfix.

Comment: Its still not sloved. Last col is still bigger (width of 25%, of container but 1-3 divs have 25%-20px padding).

Comment: I completely rebuilt it to showcase what I think is your only option.

Comment: Same thing - last div is bigger by 1%.
It sems only js/flexbox will work here.

Comment: No, all divs have exactly same size.

Comment: Indeed, true. But there is still problem with "pixel-perfect".

Atm Im testing display:inline-block and text-align: justify.
Then idea of @Kaivosukeltaja with overflow-x hidden.

Comment: Man, this really solved your problem... and you wouldn't even upvote. Shame on you.

Comment: Looking for best solution connexo, and Im new here so I dont really know how to vote (this green mark? or arrow up?). Everyone here helpt in some way.

Comment: The green mark and arrows are explained when you hover with the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of floats, you could define the columns as `display: inline-block`. Set the box-sizing as others have suggested but don't remove it for the fourth one. Prevent wrapping for the wrapper (pun not intended) and hide the horizontal overflow. This will hide the extra padding of the fourth column. If you need extra rows I believe you'll need `<br />` tags every four rows.

```css
html, body { box-sizing: border-box; }
* { box-sizing: inherit; }

.wrapper {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding: 50px 0px;
}
.wrapper .services-box {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: normal;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0 20px 20px 0;
}
.wrapper .services-box .service {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="services-box">
    <div class="service">
      <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </p>
          <a href="#">More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="services-box">
    <div class="service">
      <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </p>
          <a href="#">More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="services-box">
    <div class="service">
      <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </p>
          <a href="#">More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="services-box">
    <div class="service">
      <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </p>
          <a href="#">More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br /> <!-- NOTE: Line break here for the next row! -->
  <div class="services-box">
    <div class="service">
      <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </p>
          <a href="#">More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="services-box">
    <div class="service">
      <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </p>
          <a href="#">More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="services-box">
    <div class="service">
      <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </p>
          <a href="#">More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="services-box">
    <div class="service">
      <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </p>
          <a href="#">More</a>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: your idea is working, but it require hack with inline-block gap + those nasty <br>

Comment: Instead of `<br />` you could use `:nth-of-type(4n)::after` on every 4th element, or `:nth-of-type(4n+1)::before` on every 5th element to force a new line using a pseudo element.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add it in your css:

```
*, *:after, *:before {
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

EXAMPLE:

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 50px 0px;
}
.wrapper .services-box {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0 20px 20px 0;
}
.wrapper .services-box:nth-of-type(4n+4) {
  padding: 0 0 20px 0;
}
.wrapper .services-box .service {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
*, *:after, *:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="services-box">
    <div class="service">
      <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        <p>
          <a href="#">More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="services-box">
    <div class="service">
      <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        <p>
          <a href="#">More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="services-box">
    <div class="service">
      <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        <p>
          <a href="#">More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="services-box">
    <div class="service">
      <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        <p>
          <a href="#">More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---